# Speeding up loops over a Numpy array

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy

In my code I have for loop that indexes over a multidimensional numpy array and does some operation using the sub-array that is obtained at each iteration. It looks like this

```
for sub in Arr:
  #do stuff using sub
```

Now the stuff that is done using `sub` is fully vectorized, so it should be efficient. On the other hand this loop iterates about `~10^5`  times and is the bottleneck. Do you think I will get an improvement by offloading this part to C. I am somewhat reluctant to do so because the `do stuff using sub` uses broadcasting, slicing, smart-indexing tricks that would be tedious to write in plain C. I would also welcome thoughts and suggestions about how to deal with broadcasting, slicing, smart-indexing when offloading computation to C.

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems to me that you are using an optimized processes for what it was intended for. I don't see a reason not to use it...

Comment: @soandos Could you elaborate. I did not quite understand you, especially what the 'it' in your comment refers to.

Comment: @san: for * in Arr was designed to be very good at going though the array. It would seem then, that one should use it. I do not know how much of it difference it could make though, honestly, as 10^5 times is not all that much (on a standard 1.66 ghz computer, one can go through well over 330 million interations a second through a loop) and so a better question would be: how can you speed up your "do stuff"

Comment: @soandos Thanks for your advice. What I am hearing from you is that for loop does not add much overhead. The `do stuff` is vectorized numpy code that does not create redundant intermediates. So I am not sure how much it can be sped up. Maybe it can be. I am willing to test that out, but am looking for a less tedious way of handling broadcast and smart indexing.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why you need it if you are going to hit every element anyway. If you want to find a way to do smart indexing and broadcasting in C, or how to speed it up in python, I suggest you start another thread.

Comment: Have you played with Cython?  It won't fix your algorithm, but it will strip out a lot of the python overhead.

Comment: @matt Cython is what I have in mind if I want to move parts of it to C. But will it handle broadcast, slicing etc ? Or do I have to explicitly code them into low level loops. That is something I want to avoid.

Comment: @san - maybe you even don't have to iterate over the array. If you show us more details from your `do stuff`, we can find a better solution without a loop.

Comment: @soandos - That's true for lists, but not for numpy arrays. There's a relatively large overhead for accessing an individual element of a numpy array from python (compared to a list).  `for item in somearray` actually can be the bottleneck in cases where the inner part of the loop is fast.  This is where cython is your friend! :)

Comment: I *think* Cython is numpy aware, but I don't know how deep that runs.  Running your existing python (plus some type annotations, etc) through Cython is pretty low commitment.  I would suggest trying that and seeing if your performance is acceptable.  I'm sure you're profiling, but I'm often surprised at which parts of my code are actually the bottlenecks.  I second JoshAdel's answer as a good place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

San you can take a look at `scipy.weave`. You can use `scipy.weave.blitz` to transparently translate your expression into `C++` code and run it. It will handle slicing automatically and get rid of temporaries, but you claim that the body of your `for` loop does not create temporaries so your milage may vary.

However if you want to replace your entire for loop with something more efficient then you could make use of `scipy.inline`. The drawback is that you have to write `C++` code. This should not be too hard because you can use `Blitz++` syntax which is very close to numpy array expressions. Slicing is directly supported, broadcasting however is not.

There are two work arounds:

1. is to use the numpy-C api and use multi-dimensional iterators. They transparently handle broadcasting. However you are invoking the Numpy runtime so there might be some overhead. The other option, and possibly the simpler option is to use the usual matrix notation for broadcasting. Broadcast operations can be written as outer-products with vector of all ones. The good thing is that `Blitz++` will not actually create this temporary broadcasted arrays in memory, it will figure out how to wrap it into an equivalent loop.
2. For the second option take a look at http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/docs/blitz_3.html#SEC88 for index place holders. As long as your matrix has less than 11 dimensions you are fine. This link shows how they can be used to form outer products http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/docs/blitz_3.html#SEC99 (search for outer products to go to the relevant part of the document).

Answer (score 6):

If you can't 'vectorize' the entire operation and looping is indeed the bottleneck, then I highly recommend using Cython. I've been dabbling around with it recently and it is straightforward to work with and has a decent interface with numpy. For something like a langevin integrator I saw a 115x speedup over a decent implementation in numpy. See the documentation here:

http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html

and I also recommend looking at the following [paper](http://sage.math.washington.edu/home/dagss/numerical-cython-preprint.pdf)

You may see satisfactory speedups by just typing the input array and the loop counter, but if you want to leverage the full potential of cython, then you are going to have to hardcode the equivalent broadcasting.

Answer (score 1):

Besides using Cython, you can write the bottle-neck part(s) in Fortran. Then use f2py to compile it to Python .pyd file.