# Matrix inversion (3,3) python - hard coded vs numpy.linalg.inv

Tags: python, performance, numpy, matrix

For a large number of matrices i need to compute a distance measure defined as:

[image: dist(A,B) = 0.5 * tr(A^-1 * B + B^-1 * A)]

Although I do know that matrix inversion is strongly discouraged, I do not see a way around it. Therefore I tried to improve the performance by hard coding the matrix inversion, as all matrices are of size (3,3).

I expected it to be at least a tiny improvement, yet it is not.

Why is numpy.linalg.inv faster/more performant than this hard-coded matrix inversion?

Further, what alternatives do I have to improve this bottleneck?

```
def inversion(m):    
    m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9 = m.flatten()
    determinant = m1*m5*m9 + m4*m8*m3 + m7*m2*m6 - m1*m6*m8 - m3*m5*m7 - m2*m4*m9  
    return np.array([[m5*m9-m6*m8, m3*m8-m2*m9, m2*m6-m3*m5],
                     [m6*m7-m4*m9, m1*m9-m3*m7, m3*m4-m1*m6],
                     [m4*m8-m5*m7, m2*m7-m1*m8, m1*m5-m2*m4]])/determinant
```

For a timing comparison with a random 3*3 matrix:

```
%timeit np.linalg.inv(a)
```

100000 loops, best of 3: 12.5 µs per loop

```
%timeit inversion(a)
```

100000 loops, best of 3: 13.9 µs per loop

Closely related yet not at all a duplicate is this [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154926/efficient-extraction-of-patch-features-over-an-image) on code-review, which explains the background and the whole function.

**EDIT:** As @Divakar suggested in the comment, m.ravel() instead of m.flatten() is improving the inversion a little so that the timing comparison now yields:

numpy - 100000 loops, best of 3: 12.6 µs per loop

hard coded - 100000 loops, best of 3: 12.8 µs per loop

Although the gap is closing, the hard coded one is yet slower. How so?

Comment: Use `m.ravel()` for view and hence some boost?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Why? C, that's why (and some vectorised magic).

Comment: Would you thus conclude that hard-coded python could not be faster than numpy.linalg.inv?

Comment: Store  the reciprocal of `determinant` and then use it for multiplications with the (3x3) array? Not sure if you would see any boost here tho. The [`idea`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41945198/3293881).

Comment: @NikolasRieble it depends on the case, implementation and numpy's backends.

Comment: @Korvigo, could you elaborate or link information? In which case could it be faster?

Comment: @Divakar no improvement using the reciprocal

Comment: In your original formula is that matmul or pointwise mul?

Comment: @paul panzer matrix multiplication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a humble optimisation, saving 9 multiplications and 3 subtractions

```
def inversion(m):    
    m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9 = m.ravel()
    inv = np.array([[m5*m9-m6*m8, m3*m8-m2*m9, m2*m6-m3*m5],
                    [m6*m7-m4*m9, m1*m9-m3*m7, m3*m4-m1*m6],
                    [m4*m8-m5*m7, m2*m7-m1*m8, m1*m5-m2*m4]])
    return inv / np.dot(inv[0], m[:, 0])
```

You can squeeze out a few more ops (another 24 multiplications if I'm counting correctly) by doing the entire trace in one go:

```
def det(m):
   m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9 = m.ravel()
   return np.dot(m[:, 0], [m5*m9-m6*m8, m3*m8-m2*m9, m2*m6-m3*m5])
   # or try m1*(m5*m9-m6*m8) + m4*(m3*m8-m2*m9) + m7*(m2*m6-m3*m5)
   # probably the fastest would be to inline the two calls to det
   # I'm not doing it here because of readability but you should try it

def dist(m, n):
   m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9 = m.ravel()
   n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9 = n.ravel()
   return 0.5 * np.dot(
       m.ravel()/det(m) + n.ravel()/det(n),
       [m5*n9-m6*n8, m6*n7-m4*n9, m4*n8-m5*n7, n3*m8-n2*m9, n1*m9-n3*m7,
        n2*m7-n1*m8, m2*n6-m3*n5, m3*n4-m1*n6, m1*n5-m2*n4])
```

Ok here is the inlined version:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def dist(m, n):
   m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9 = m.ravel()
   n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9 = n.ravel()
   return 0.5 * np.dot(
       m.ravel()/(m1*(m5*m9-m6*m8) + m4*(m3*m8-m2*m9) + m7*(m2*m6-m3*m5))
       + n.ravel()/(n1*(n5*n9-n6*n8) + n4*(n3*n8-n2*n9) + n7*(n2*n6-n3*n5)),
       [m5*n9-m6*n8, m6*n7-m4*n9, m4*n8-m5*n7, n3*m8-n2*m9, n1*m9-n3*m7,
        n2*m7-n1*m8, m2*n6-m3*n5, m3*n4-m1*n6, m1*n5-m2*n4])

def dist_np(m, n):
    return 0.5 * np.diag(np.linalg.inv(m)@n + np.linalg.inv(n)@m).sum()

for i in range(3):
    A, B = np.random.random((2,3,3))
    print(dist(A, B), dist_np(A, B))
    print('pp     ', timeit('f(A,B)', number=10000, globals={'f':dist, 'A':A, 'B':B}))
    print('numpy  ', timeit('f(A,B)', number=10000, globals={'f':dist_np, 'A':A, 'B':B}))
```

prints:

```
2.20109953156 2.20109953156
pp      0.13215381593909115
numpy   0.4334693900309503
7.50799877993 7.50799877993
pp      0.13934064202476293
numpy   0.32861811900511384
-0.780284449609 -0.780284449609
pp      0.1258618349675089
numpy   0.3110764700686559
```

Note that you can make another substantial saving by batch-processing using a vectorised version of the function. The test computes all 10,000 pairwise distances between two batches of 100 matrices:

```
def dist(m, n):
    m = np.moveaxis(np.reshape(m, m.shape[:-2] + (-1,)), -1, 0)
    n = np.moveaxis(np.reshape(n, n.shape[:-2] + (-1,)), -1, 0)
    m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m8, m9 = m
    n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9 = n
    return 0.5 * np.einsum("i...,i...->...",
        m/(m1*(m5*m9-m6*m8) + m4*(m3*m8-m2*m9) + m7*(m2*m6-m3*m5))
        + n/(n1*(n5*n9-n6*n8) + n4*(n3*n8-n2*n9) + n7*(n2*n6-n3*n5)),
        [m5*n9-m6*n8, m6*n7-m4*n9, m4*n8-m5*n7, n3*m8-n2*m9, n1*m9-n3*m7,
         n2*m7-n1*m8, m2*n6-m3*n5, m3*n4-m1*n6, m1*n5-m2*n4])

def dist_np(m, n):
    return 0.5 * (np.linalg.inv(m)@n + np.linalg.inv(n)@m)[..., np.arange(3), np.arange(3)].sum(axis=-1)

for i in range(3):
    A = np.random.random((100,1,3,3))
    B = np.random.random((1,100,3,3))
    print(np.allclose(dist(A, B), dist_np(A, B)))
    print('pp     ', timeit('f(A,B)', number=100, globals={'f':dist, 'A':A, 'B':B}))
    print('numpy  ', timeit('f(A,B)', number=100, globals={'f':dist_np, 'A':A, 'B':B}))
```

prints:

```
True
pp      0.14652886800467968
numpy   1.5294789629988372
True
pp      0.1482033939100802
numpy   1.6455406049499288
True
pp      0.1279512889450416
numpy   1.370200254023075
```

Comment: Although a nice move, it performs worse (=slower) than the version in the question. %timeit np.linalg.inv(a) - 100000 loops, best of 3: 17.2 µs per loop
%timeit inversion_paul(a) - 10000 loops, best of 3: 21.2 µs per loop
%timeit inversion_niko(a) - 100000 loops, best of 3: 19.2 µs per loop

Comment: @NikolasRieble Have a look at the latest update. In my benchmarks it's a factor 2-3 faster than numpy.

Comment: @NicolasRIeble Vectorised version gives a 10x speedup over numpy when batch-processing.

Comment: Impressive improvement. Would you mind to take a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154926/efficient-extraction-of-patch-features-over-an-image and see how i have to extract the matrices from an image.

Comment: @NikolasRieble Assuming you have two lists of 3x3 arrays. (1) convert them to arrays A (mx3x3) B (nx3x3) (2) simply do `A = A[:, None, ...]; B = B[None, ...]` (3) passing these to the vectorised `dist` should return an `mxn` array of distances. -- Extracting the patches to a list either do a list comprehension or allocate an mx3x3 empty array and loop over the 9 pixels using advanced indexing with your coordinate list (adding all combinations of 0, 1, 2 to the two coordinates).

Comment: Becoming a fan of `np.moveaxis` aye? :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is small  overhead of creating four Python objects (four lists) when you call `np.array()`.

I've created the following file (`test.py`):

```
import numpy as np

def one():
    return np.array([[0.1,0.2,0.3],[0.4,0.5,0.6],[0.7,0.8,0.9]])

def two():
    a = np.zeros((3, 3))
    a[0,0]=0.1
    a[0,1]=0.2
    a[0,2]=0.3
    a[1,0]=0.4
    a[1,1]=0.5
    a[1,2]=0.6
    a[2,0]=0.7
    a[2,1]=0.8
    a[2,2]=0.9
    return a
```

Both `one()` and `two()` are doing the same thing. However, `one()` in the process creates four Python lists, and `two()` does not. Now:

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'from test import one' 'one()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.13 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'from test import one' 'one()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.95 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'from test import one' 'one()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'from test import two' 'two()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'from test import two' 'two()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.76 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'from test import two' 'two()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.69 usec per loop
```

I've also tried with tuples instead of lists, and the result is as expected (slower than no new Python objects but faster than lists, as tuples are non-modifiable and overhead of those is probably smaller)

```
def three():
    return np.array(((0.1, 0.2, 0.3),(0.4,0.5,0.6),(0.7,0.8,0.9)))

$ python -m timeit -s 'from test import three' 'three()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.11 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'from test import three' 'three()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.03 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s 'from test import three' 'three()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.08 usec per loop
```

Comment: Although a small improvement compared to the other answer, it adds another perspective!